# Observe a property for changes in a Class from another Library

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

Is there a way to observe changes for a property from a class that I did not write?

example:

```
public ExampleClass{
     public int SomeNumber {get; set;}
    }
```

I don't have control of the object that is being passed to me, but I need to know when SomeNumber changes.  I would have raised an event, but it's not my code.

Aside using a timer...is there a realistic way to monitor this property?

Comment: You can wrap it in a class you _did_ write.

Comment: this is an argument that is passed to me from another library.  So not an option here I don't think as I have no control over the source object.